# dancer+database on Openshift?

Tags: openshift, dancer

I am trying to deploy a dancer based application on openshift. I am unable to workaround teh following issues.

- How do I get dancer to use the openshift environment variables e.g. OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST or OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. Putting them in the config.yml files is not working i tried $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and $ENV{OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR} overriding them in the application code is not working...
- Does openshift store the console log somewhere? rhc tail does not provide the complete output...
- Is it possible to run the app on the server from a ssh shell? I tried it but am getting a permission denied error

Dancer is a perl based web framework. see https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Cookbook

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what a dancer application is, but for a java application with a mysql db on openshift, you access it with the following code

Import the following:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

then use the following as your connection string:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
Context initialContext = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/MysqlDS");

Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I hope this helps.